# TypeBuilder.GetMethod on TypeBuilder

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

`TypeBuilder.GetMethod` allows you to get a method on a generic type closed by a `TypeBuilder` so it lets me to the following:

```
TypeBuilder tb = ....
// this would throw a NotSupportedException : 
// var ec = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).
//     MakeGenericType(tb).GetMethod("get_Default");

// this works:
var ec = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(tb, typeof(EqualityComparer<>).
    GetMethod("get_Default");
```

What doesn't work (and I can't figure out how to make it work yet) is this:

```
Type collectionOf = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(tb);
// throws: 'Type must be a type provided by the runtime. 
// Parameter name: types'
var colEc = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(collectionOf, typeof(EqualityComparer<>).
    GetMethod("get_Default");
// throws NotSupportedException
colEc = typeof(EqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(collectionOf).
    GetMethod("get_Default");
```

Anyone know the answer (I hope it's 42)...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me what you're trying to do (it looks like you're missing some parentheses, among other issues), but if you're trying to get a `MethodInfo` for `EqualityComparer<ICollection<YourType>>.get_Default`, this works for me:

```
var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("test"),
             AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("test");
var tb = mb.DefineType("TestType");

var ico = typeof(ICollection<>);
var eq = typeof(EqualityComparer<>);

var m = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(eq.MakeGenericType(ico.MakeGenericType(tb)), eq.GetMethod("get_Default"));
```

Comment: No, TypeBuilder.GetMethod says the type must be a type builder type.

Comment: @JeffN825 - it works for me - what error are you seeing?  I've updated my answer to make it self contained.

Comment: This is SO bizarre. 1. Your example works in a console app for me. 2. I can't try catch the exception. 3. The stack trace DOESN't FOLLOW a logical path...at System.DefaultBinder.SelectMethod(BindingFlags bindingAttr, MethodBase[] match, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers) at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers) at System.Type.GetMethod(String name, Type[] types) at TypeSystem.TypeGenerator.GenerateGetHashCode(TypeBuilder type, IEnumerable`1 fields)

Comment: EVEN STRANGER: I can't produce the same behavior in the immediate window! It works in the immediate window.

Comment: It seems like this problem doesn't have to do with the TypeBuilder but rather some sort of strange issue occuring in the .NET runtime type binder...

Answer (score 1):

Like said earlier, you cannot do reflection on types that have not been created yet.

You need to either keep track of the methods, or ensure that you have a runtime type that is returned from called `TypeBuilder.CreaterType()`. `TypeBuilder` 'conveniently' does keep track of the created runtime type for you if it has already been created.

This goes for almost every reflection operation in `Reflection.Emit` types, not just `TypeBuilder`.

**Update:**

I have not noticed `TypeBuilder.GetMethod` before, so I am probably wrong above. Will find out the detail. :)

**Update 2: Possible solution**

<strike>Does the following work?</strike>

```
typeof(EqualityComparer<>).GetMethod("get_Default").MakeGenericMethod(tb)
```

*Should be testing :(*

Comment: The problem seems to be that I don't actually have a TypeBuilder here that I want to emit a method for....it's an EqualityComparer<ICollection<MyTypeBuilderType>>...